# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod') in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-lazyloading

I'm trying to create a micro service frontend in angular

Using this code for route :

```
import { loadRemoteModule } from './federation-utils';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_ROUTES } from '../app.routes';
import { Microfrontend } from '../core/services/microfrontends/microfrontend.types';

export function buildRoutes(options: Microfrontend[]): Routes {
  const lazyRoutes: Routes = options.map((o) => ({
    path: o.routePath,
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule(o).then((m) => m[o.ngModuleName]),
    canActivate: o.canActivate,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }));

  return [
    ...APP_ROUTES,
    ...lazyRoutes
  ];
}
```

getting this error

```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties
> of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')
```

Link : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-micro-frontend-based-on-angular

> options contains these values:

```
[
    {
        "remoteEntry": "http://localhost:4204/remoteEntry.js",
        "remoteName": "dashboard",
        "exposedModule": "DashboardModule",
        "displayName": "Dashboard",
        "routePath": "",
        "ngModuleName": "DashboardModule",
        "canActivate": [
            null
        ]
    },
    {
        "remoteEntry": "http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js",
        "remoteName": "table",
        "exposedModule": "TablePageModule",
        "displayName": "Table",
        "routePath": "table",
        "ngModuleName": "TablePageModule"
    },
    {
        "remoteEntry": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js",
        "remoteName": "register",
        "exposedModule": "RegisterPageModule",
        "displayName": "Register",
        "routePath": "signup",
        "ngModuleName": "RegisterPageModule",
        "canActivate": [
            null
        ]
    },
    {
        "remoteEntry": "http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js",
        "remoteName": "staticPage",
        "exposedModule": "StaticPageModule",
        "displayName": "Static page",
        "routePath": "static",
        "ngModuleName": "StaticPageModule"
    }
]
```

Console Output of `m[o.ngModuleName]`:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler `Angular CLI: 10.1.7,Node: 14.17.3, Angular: 10.1.6` these are the versions of angular and node that i'm using pls check

Comment: This is likely a deps issue. You should update your stack.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler i updated to angular cli 16 and node 16 but same issue i'm facing Can you pls let me know any specific version which i should install

Comment: There is likely an issue with `m[o.ngModuleName]`. Check its value.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes options contains values i have added in question above pls check

Comment: No I'm mean, check at runtime what `m[o.ngModuleName]` contains.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler when i console `m[o.ngModuleName]` it prints  `class DashboardModule {}` only

Comment: I have added screenshot also in all the three case i.e. link click i get these data for `console(m)` but for `console.log(m[o.ngModuleName])` only getting values for first one rest two are undefined

Comment: `RegisterPageModule` is not an angular module. Where does it come from ?